# Ruby: Getting an error when I use recursion to find prime numbers

Tags: ruby, recursion, prime-factoring

So I've been trying to create a method that would display an array of prime numbers for any Integer that you insert as an argument, but I've been getting the weirdest error. Can anyone explain what this error means and how to solve my problem w/o using any gems? I've tried looking on Stack Overflow and haven't found a solution. Thanks!

```
def prime_factors(num, output = [])
  factor = (2..num-1).find(0){|divisor| num % divisor == 0} #returns nil if find fails.
  output << factor if factor != 0
  prime_factors(num/factor, output)
end

prime_factors(5)
```

The error I've been receiving is:

```
`find': undefined method `call' for 0:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
in `prime_factors'
in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the docs for `Enumerable#find` (which you call in the first line of your function: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find

The parameter of `find` is called if no object of the `Enumerable` (`(2..num-1)` in your case) matches (that is, the given block always returned `false`). So `find` tries to find a Number for which `num % divisor` is equal to `0`, but doesn't find one. Then, it calls the function supplied as parameter. You pass `0` for that parameter. So it tries to invoke `0` as a function (which is done by executing the `call` Method: `0.call`). But `0` of class `Fixnum` has no such method (it is not a function but a number). That generates the error message.

Comment: I see...thanks! I thought `find` returned `ifnone` for which the block fails, but looking back through the ruby documentation I see that ifnone is a method call. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I think the most elegant solution would be to give no parameter to `find` so it returns `nil` and setting `factor` to `0` in this case: `factor = (2..num-1).find{|divisor| num % divisor == 0} or 0`

Comment: I agree that giving no parameter would be an elegant solution if it worked, but the problem I'm having is that I can't coerce nil to be evaluated on the next line `output << factor if factor != nil` I get the following error: `nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)`

Comment: If you write `or 0` after the `find` in the first line (see my previous comment) then `factor` will be `0` when `find` returned `nil`.

Comment: Oh, better write `||` instead of `or` or it won't work as advertised.

Comment: I'm sorry, did you mean to pass `||0` as the parameter or include it at the end of my block? I tried both ways and received two varying error messages:  `syntax error, unexpected ||, expecting ')'` for `factor = (2..num-1).find(||0){|divisor| num % divisor == 0}`  and `nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)` for `factor = (2..num-1).find(){|divisor| num % divisor == 0||0}`

Comment: I meant: `factor = (2..num-1).find{|divisor| num % divisor == 0} || 0`

Comment: Wouldn't that affect my recursion call then? I'm getting the error: `divided by 0`

Comment: Yes, you have to check for `0` in the division at the end, but that would also be the case if the code worked as you intended in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because of find(0) in the below line

```
factor = (2..num-1).find(0)
```

since find method is unable to trigger call for "0 i.e fixnum" as argument.
I don't know why you are doing that.

Instead, you can try this logic

```
(2..num-1).each do |i| 
  is_prime = true
  (2..Math.sqrt(i)).each { |j| is_prime = false if i % j == 0 }
  output << i if is_prime
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll definitely try your solution tomorrow as I walk through the logic.